# How to click a hidden input file with a button on it's row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to replace the original `input type="file"` with a `<button>` with bootstrap style. The idea is hide it with jquery `hide()` at the first place. And then trigger it with a button.

Things works well when there's only one button. But whenever another button is added. The select dialogue keep displaying according to the number of file input.

I need each button to select it's input-file. So I give it a unique id with wildcard selectors. And it still not work. Here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<form method="get" action="">File Upload 1.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
    <button type="button" id="browse1" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="">File Upload 2.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
    <button type="button" id="browse2" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="">File Upload 3.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="3" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
    <button type="button" id="browse3" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=file]').hide();
    $('button[id^=browse]').click(function () {
        $('input[id^=file]').click();
    })
});
```

DEMO HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/txvq7hxv/4/

Please help me out! :(

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You could just use CSS to style the label.  And hide the file input/button.  Should work fine like that.

Comment: Thank you anyway, @AndrewIce. But it's not the point. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You better not use id's if you want more then one!
Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/txvq7hxv/6/
Attention: it's a quick hack, not for reuse.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[id^=file]').hide();
$('.browse').click(function () {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).closest('form').find('input[id^=file]').click();
})
});
```

HTML

```
    <form method="get" action="">File Upload 1.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
    <button type="button" id="browse" class="btn btn-primary browse"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="">File Upload 2.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
    <button type="button" id="browse" class="btn btn-primary browse"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="">File Upload 3.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="3" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
    <button type="button" id="browse" class="btn btn-primary browse"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
```

Comment: You warn against using duplicate IDs, yet your answer and fiddle have them.

Comment: Either rsvmrk and Robert Rozas methods are working. But @Robert is the first. Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks, as I said it was a quick hack. You better do not use id's if you want more element then one. I do not remove the #browse elements cause the CSS used it for HTML design. You better you CSS class too.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[id^=file]').hide();
$('.btn.btn-primary').click(function () {
    $(this).prev('input').click();
})
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cj3fp3dm/1/

Comment: This works only if the file input is just prior to the button tag, which may change.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=file]').hide();
    $('.btn').on("click", function () {
       $(this).parent('form').find('input[id^=file]').click();
    });
});
```

This JavaScript should work, try it...

http://jsfiddle.net/txvq7hxv/19/

Answer (score 1):

OK, this answer may be slightly offtopic, but it is about the approach. Here's what most of the jQuery Plugins  which handle/replace the upload button are doing.

Barebone example..

**HTML:-**

```
 <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
   <div class="input-append">
     <div class="uneditable-input">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileupload-exists"></i>
     </div>
     <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      <span class="fileupload-new">Select Logo Image</span>
      <!--<input type="file" />-->
      <input type="file" name="uploadfile" value="" id="filePhoto">
     </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.btn-file>input {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0;
opacity: 0;
font-size: 23px;
direction: ltr;
cursor: pointer;
}

.fileupload .btn {
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 21px;
margin-left: -5px;
}
.btn-file {
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-default {
background: #e4e7ea;
color: #636e7b;
}
```

Working Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/539ex9rs/).

If you need to **further enhance** the buttons' features **[here's the plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-examples)** that is doing exactly what you need, maybe not reinventing the wheel would speed up your workflow, if you are learning then you should keep experimenting and also keep the already finished product for a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each file input tag is in its own form tag, as your example is structured, you could use the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to get the form and then use that as context to find the file input tag. This means that the structure within the form tag doesn't have to keep the file input just before the button tag, as is required with [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function, and doesn't nail you down to having the button as a specific depth from the form tag, as is required with the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function. Also, the [pure HTML/CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26145696/892327) from Mohd would be my suggested approach.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=file]').hide();
    $('button[id^=browse]').click(function () {
        console.log("<button> clicked:" + $(this).attr("id"));
        console.log("Closest <form>:" + $(this).closest("form").attr("id"));
        console.log("File <input> from <form>:" + $(this).closest("form").find('input[id^=file]').attr("id"));
        $(this).closest("form").find('input[id^=file]').click();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="" id="form1">File Upload 1.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
    <button type="button" id="browse1" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="" id="form2">File Upload 2.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
    <button type="button" id="browse2" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="" id="form3">File Upload 3.
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="3" />
    <input type="file" name="file3" id="file3" />
    <button type="button" id="browse3" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
</form>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why everybody is using JavaScript for this simple task.

Just make use of the HTML `<label>` Element without any JavaScript like so:

```html
<label>
  <span class="btn btn-primary">Button Text</span>
  <input type="file" name="photo" style="display:none">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

When i tried your jsfiddle I clicked on 1 button and I had 3 file browser pop-up so your button are triggering evrey file input. Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=file]').hide();
    $('button[id^=browse]').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('input[type=file]').click();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function to get the file input.

```js
//$(document).ready(functionhz
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[id^=file]').hide();
    $('a[id^=browse]').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('input[type=file]').click();
    })
});
```

```css
div.content div.btns_wrapper div.item {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1171px) {
  /* line 179, -RtixBalkanStudioXConvert */
  div.content div.btns_wrapper div.item.index {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* line 185, -RtixBalkanStudioXConvert */

div.content div.btns_wrapper div.item.first {
  text-align: left;
}


/* line 188, -RtixBalkanStudioXConvert */

div.content div.btns_wrapper div.item.last {
  text-align: right;
}


/* line 193, -RtixBalkanStudioXConvert */

div.content div.textarea_wrapper {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 165px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/1/file/52742/name/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="item index">
  <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="1" />
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
  <a href="javascript:" id="browse" class="btn btn-primary browse"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/ixV1pn/btn_reset.jpg" alt=""></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer? Its not immediately obvious that you've changed anything in the javascript code. A note about `$(this).prev('input[type=file]').click()` and why this works would be good.